# upon click/change event - pass the iteration item record to js file

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

```
    <template for:each={rates} for:item="rate" for:index="rindex" > 
        <tr key={rate.Price_Authority__c} class='accordion slds-hint-parent' onclick={handleAccordian} >
            <td role="gridcell" class='slds-text-align--center'>
                <lightning-input type="checkbox" value={rate.Comment} data-item={rate} onclick={handleChildClick}></lightning-input>
            </td>
            <td role="gridcell">
                <div class="slds-truncate slds-cell-wrap">{rate.Price_Authority__c}</div>
            </td>

        </tr>
    </template>


handleChildClick(event){
    alert(typeof event.target.getAttribute('data-item'));  --> string
    alert(event.target.getAttribute('data-item')); ----------> '[object Object]'
}
```

upon click/change event on the input box...i'm not able to get the iteration item object in the `event.target.getAttribute('data-item')`. i'm getting string instead of Object

Comment: You should probably create a child component instead of using data attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object that you need is already in memory so you could just use the index:

```
<template for:each={rates} for:item="rate" for:index="rindex" > 
  <tr key={rate.Price_Authority__c}>
    <td>
      <lightning-input
        data-index={rindex}
        type="checkbox"
        value={rate.Comment}
        onclick={handleChildClick}
      ></lightning-input>
    </td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

```
handleChildClick(event){
  const rate = this.rates[event.target.dataset.index];
  // do something awesome!
}
```

Comment: Thank you kashida....Other than passing index or string, can't we pass entire object to JS thru event object.

Answer (score 1):

HTML `data-` attributes hold strings, not JavaScript objects. When you assign the object value `{rate}` to it, what you get is the string representation `[object Object]`.

Instead of trying to place an object in this attribute, store some unique attribute, such as the Salesforce Id of an sObject. Then, your event handling code can reacquire the instance as needed.

Comment: Hi David, Thankyou for your help. 
Since i m getting response from webservice i won't have sfdcid...i want to know whether it is possible to pass an object through JS event object in LWC.
updated the HTML with name={rate} and in the 
JS i m getting:
  typeof event.target.getAttribute('name') ---- object 
  event.target.getAttribute('name'); ---- null

Comment: @VishnuVardhan HTML attributes do not hold object values. You'd have to encode the object as a string via JSON or some other serialization.